# How can I give external developers access to only some files of my website and keep track of their changes?

Tags: git

Unfortunately I have a website where you can't develop on locally with a subset of data, so I have always done that on some non production servers part of my cluster.

I now have to give development access to some external developers, and I want to be able to do that on a file by file basis. I will need to review every push they make to make sure they didn't expose anything with something as simple as `echo $db_password` or anything like that.

I almost certainly need to use a revision system.

Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this. You're going to allow them to write code directly to production, but you don't trust them not to write `echo $db_password`? Are you going to manually review every file every 5 seconds when they save it? What prevents you from seeding some realistic data and developing locally?

Comment: So, you're outsourcing some development work to some off-shore contracting shop, and you can't figure out how to make it work? The real problem here, it seems, is not really code control related.

Comment: I can go after those people if they decide to do something rouge. Thank you Sam, you certainly know better. SO is becoming such a trollfest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will need to review every push they make to make sure ....

For that purpose, you can use [git server side hooks](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks); For example, [here](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Server-Side-Hook) the author demonstrate how to use *update* hooks to enforce a specific commit message format. The *pre-receive* hook should also be relevant.